# Can we use ngx-lightbox with async pipe?

Tags: angular, lightbox

Before I rewrite my component, I'd like to ask if that's really necessary.

In the [official documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-lightbox) they're building an "album" object containing three properties (src, caption, tumb)

Obviously the "open" method expects that.

As mentioned, I do not subscribe to my API's observable in the component, I just pass it to the async pipe:

```
course$: Observable<Course>;
this.course$ = this.courseService.getSingle(this.courseId);
```

(...)

```
<ng-container *ngIf="course$ | async as course; else loading">
```

I mean everything's alright with the documentation. I could just subscribe in the component and build that album-array... However, before doing so, I wonder if there's a way to keep my current solution.

The course$: Observable; also contains an Array of Objects, but it looks differently:

```
export interface Course {
  id: number
  images?: Image[];
}

export interface Image {
  id: number;
  imageURL: string;
  description: string;
}
```

My goal is to build something like described in the documentation (easy part)

```
<div *ngFor="let image of course.images; let i=index">
  <img [src]="image.imageURL" (click)="open(i)" />
</div>
```

The tricky part might be the "open" event listener which would access said "album" array they built in the componenent's constructor...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I answer this myself. I subscribed to the observable in the component and build that array. Seems to be the only way then.